# Express app.use routes with optional params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I'm trying to add optional parameters to Express in all of my routes. Here is a part of my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const apiRoutes = require('./routes/apiRoutes');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(
    '/api/:param?',
    bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }),
    bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, parameterLimit: 50000 }),
    apiRoutes,
);
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is started on port *:${port}`);
});
```

I have all of my routes in apiRoutes file defined like:

```
router.get('system/versionInfo', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('return Version info');
});

router.get('system/info', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('return system info');
});
```

I would like the `param?` to be optional so sometimes will be passed sometimes not. Now if I do not pass that `param`, the routes are returning 404 error (Not Found). If I pass it, all is working fine.

So for example if I run:

```
'/api/test/system/versionInfo'
```

all is fine, but if I run

```
'/api/system/versionInfo'
```

it returns 404. I would like in both cases to return valid route.

Comment: Just add a second `app.use` call without the parameter. `app.use('/api', apiRoutes);`

Comment: Not going to work, then route '/api/test/system/versionInfo' wont work :(

Comment: Try to use `mergeParams` when creating `Router`

Comment: Did you actually try this? AFAIK, the first matching route processes the request, so adding it below the param route shouldn't have any effect other than preventing the 404.

Comment: @ChrisG yes i did its not working 404 is returned for other routes

Comment: @KrzysztofSzostak I tried but that also is not working :( or Im putting it wrong

Comment: That's weird because it works perfectly fine for me. single file demo: https://pastebin.com/80PdZciS

Comment: @ChrisG It looks like its working now :), just to check everything ... I have a question why do I have to define 2 time app.use and pass apiRoutes ???

Comment: Maybe there *is* a way to do this with a single `use()` call. I don't know. All I know is that express goes through the routes you set up in order and uses the first match it finds. And given that inserting an optional "folder" in the middle of the URL is a bit weird, this two-use() solution seems likely to be the only one. So to answer your question: you have to define two rules because that's the only way to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you can you post that so I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since express will go over all routes looking for a match, you can pass your `apiRoutes` to multiple `app.use()` calls, like this:

**in apiRoutes.js:**

```
router.get('system/info', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('return system info');
});
```

**in app.js:**

```
app.use('/api/:param?',
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.params.param == "test") console.log("test param detected");
    next();
  },
  apiRoutes,
);

app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

The `/api/test/system/info` route will match the first rule, the `api/system/info` route will match the second rule.